# mysql query error for my query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'VALUES (1039,200,'2',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1)' at line
>   1

for this query:

> INSERT INTO anu_donations 
>   (projectid,donation_amount,donated_by,donated_by_uid,donation_details,
>   comments,payment_medium,donor_comments,created_by)
>
> VALUES (1039,100,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1),  VALUES
>   (1039,200,'2',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1);

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `VALUES` once

```
INSERT INTO anu_donations    
(projectid,donation_amount,donated_by,donated_by_uid,donation_details, 
comments,payment_medium,donor_comments,created_by)

VALUES 
   (1039,100,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1), 
   (1039,200,'2',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1);
```

See [INSERT in the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Statement for [`INSERT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is as follows:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Thus, you can see that `VALUES` is used once. Thus, you need to change your SQL as follows:

```
INSERT INTO anu_donations (projectid,donation_amount,donated_by,donated_by_uid,donation_details, comments,payment_medium,donor_comments,created_by)

VALUES (1039,100,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1), (1039,200,'2',NULL,NULL,NULL,'cash',NULL,1);
```